# Firebase Analytics : How to get the multiple parameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I'm using firebase analytics for my game (made with unity). I 'have been using this simple log, which gives me some values in the debug view.

```
    //1 Loggin our event
    Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(
        //2 Event that being logged (can be own string for custom event)
        FirebaseAnalytics.EventLevelStart,
          //3 parameters associated with event Parameter Name, Parameter Value
          new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter(FirebaseAnalytics.ParameterLevel, sceneIndex_i),
          new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter(FirebaseAnalytics.ParameterLevelName, sceneName_i)
          );
```

but for some reasons that I can't figure out, it's impossible for me to get the datas on download (csv) or even see it into the firebase events. The only thing I get is how many times the event "level_start" has been fired, without any clue on which level the log has been fired.

Is it possible to know something like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Custom Parameters are not represented directly in your Analytics
> reports, they can be used as filters in audience definitions that can
> be applied to every report.

You may be interested in "user properties", User Properties are similar is some respects to Custom Event Parameters -- both add context to an event so you can better understand the nature of each event.

However, User Properties differ from Custom Event Parameters in the following ways :

1. You set User Property values once (via the setUserProperty API) and they persist across all lifecycles of the app.
2. After setting as User Property value, it is automatically associated with every event that is logged thereafter.
3. If you register the User Property in the Analytics "User Properties" tab, you can use it to filter all of your reports.

Once you have Registered your properties in Analytics, you will be able to find your defined properties in Analytics after several hours (there is a delay).

You can find the documentation here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/properties#set_user_properties

If you need deeper insights into your users and analytics, it would be worth looking at BigQuery but this does require the Blaze Plan

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. This unfortunate that it requires a Blaze Plan.

Answer (score 0):

as @didibyte said, it is not possible.

However, for those who are now looking a workaround to avoid to have the blaze plan :  Codify your datas so you can get as much information in one row. i.e : If you want to know in which lvl your player died or won, codify the value:

```
//Param value length = 100 characters long max
string value = lvlName+"-"+winStatus;
//It will give in my case lvl1-win
//lvl2-loose
//and so on...
```

then you just have to use excel and mark the "-" as a separator and you will have all your datas needed.