# Firebase analytics & Big Table with mutli-parameter filtering

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, bigtable, google-analytics-filters

Sorry if this question has been answered before.  I have asked Firebase directly and gotten no response.

Our company product is sort of a B2B to C offering.  Our clients are schools & employers, while our end users are their employees.  Each employer usually wants reporting data for only their own employees.  I would like to be able to generate reports in such a fashion.

My plan is to use multiple paramenters in every event, including a client_id parameter, or perhaps even a full user_profile json object.

Will I be able to multi-parameter filtering this way (ie first filter by client, then by events), or in Big Table, create reports client by client?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67196284/firebase-analytics-how-to-get-the-multiple-parameter)  that might be helpful for using multi-parameter filtering in Firebase Analytics. Another way might be creating an [audience](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en) as with that it lets you select multiple conditional filters. Also you might try a workaround using [BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090396/how-to-select-multiple-custom-firebase-event-parameters-in-bigquery).

Regarding creating reports client by client in BigTable you might want to check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-metrics) and this other one about filters in [Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/filters).